# Launching a window causes error 566 concerning buffer sysa

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Inside a window, I try to open another window, like this:

```
RUN "OtherWindow.w":U (
INPUT        E-Par1,
...
INPUT-OUTPUT E-Par4,
...
INPUT        E-Par11
).
```

Usually, this works fine, but now I get error 566 concerning buffer `sysa`.

There exists a table `sysa`, but I don't see the link between that table and the current error message.

In top of this, the first line of my `OtherWindow.w` looks as follows:

```
MESSAGE "first line" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

I don't see that message, so my second window does not even get opened. That second window has been compiled and the corresponding `*.r` file is present in the same directory as the `*.r` file of the first window.

Does anybody know what this means? Is the mentioned buffer `sysa` related to my table `sysa` or is this just a coincidence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the **exact** error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 566 indicates here be monsters:

```
<program> Unable to find shared buffer for <buffer>. (566)

You used a DEFINE SHARED BUFFER <name> statement in a program.  
When you ran the program, no existing buffer <name> was found.
```

The program you are attempting to run has a `define shared buffer` statement. Which will compile just fine.

But at run time, if the shared buffer has not been defined before the call with `define new shared buffer` will result in error 566.

Note that `shared` is an archaic construct that stems from before parameters could be passed to procedures. It can be also be (ab)used for variables.

Comment: In my specific case, the monster has eaten almost my entire `otherwindow.w`: it seems that half of that file has been removed in some way, causing the very weird behaviour.